# How can be C arithmetic so inexact?

Tags: c, math, loops

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Floating point inaccuracy examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples)

In my computer and using g++ I found that:

```
21*3.6 ==  75.60000000000000852651
```

and that ruins a simple loop. See this code:

```
  double incr=3.6;
  double limit=21*3.6;
  printf (" ¿%f == %.20f? \n", limit, limit);
  for (double x=0.0; x<limit; x += incr) {
    printf (" x %f < limit %f (dif = %.20f) \n", x, limit, limit-x);
  }
```

and its output:

```
 ¿75.600000 == 75.60000000000000852651? 
x=0.000000, limit=75.600000 (dif = 75.60000000000000852651) 
x=3.600000, limit=75.600000 (dif = 72.00000000000001421085) 
x=7.200000, limit=75.600000 (dif = 68.40000000000000568434) 
x=10.800000, limit=75.600000 (dif = 64.80000000000001136868) 
x=14.400000, limit=75.600000 (dif = 61.20000000000000994760) 
x=18.000000, limit=75.600000 (dif = 57.60000000000000852651) 
x=21.600000, limit=75.600000 (dif = 54.00000000000000710543) 
x=25.200000, limit=75.600000 (dif = 50.40000000000000568434) 
x=28.800000, limit=75.600000 (dif = 46.80000000000000426326) 
x=32.400000, limit=75.600000 (dif = 43.20000000000000284217) 
x=36.000000, limit=75.600000 (dif = 39.60000000000000142109) 
x=39.600000, limit=75.600000 (dif = 36.00000000000000000000) 
x=43.200000, limit=75.600000 (dif = 32.39999999999999857891) 
x=46.800000, limit=75.600000 (dif = 28.79999999999999715783) 
x=50.400000, limit=75.600000 (dif = 25.19999999999999573674) 
x=54.000000, limit=75.600000 (dif = 21.59999999999999431566) 
x=57.600000, limit=75.600000 (dif = 17.99999999999999289457) 
x=61.200000, limit=75.600000 (dif = 14.39999999999999147349) 
x=64.800000, limit=75.600000 (dif = 10.79999999999999715783) 
x=68.400000, limit=75.600000 (dif = 7.20000000000000284217) 
x=72.000000, limit=75.600000 (dif = 3.60000000000000852651) 
x=75.600000, limit=75.600000 (dif = 0.00000000000001421085)
```

that shows that the last time the loop should not be executed
but for the error!

Suggestions?

Comment: http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: There should be a special link for UltraFAQs.

Comment: have you tried float instead?

Comment: We need #SOSTDAnswer1: That's how floating-point works that we can flag these questions with.

Comment: In short: floating point numbers in C don't have infinite precision. That is, when doing paper+pencil arithmetic, you can be as precise as you need with numbers - just write down another digit. In computing, where a double only has 64 bits to encode *any* number, you lose precision. It's a given that C floating point arithmetic will be inexact! The solution, then, is to add some tolerance to your comparisons. Either truncate after a few decimal places, or instead of saying (a == b), use logic to say, for example, "a is within +/- 0.01 of b"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to read this:

[What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

You are using a floating point number, and you need to know what floating point means. What it can do, and what it can't do.  There are numbers that you can represent in a few digits of text, that can't be exactly represented in a fixed-point, or floating-point binary numeric form. You are making assumptions about floating point that are not specifically related only to C programming, but to any computer system using floating point numbers.

Comment: Sure ! But, 21*3.6 does not seems as a dangerous and complex calculation, does it?

Comment: @cibercitizen: It is. Read the linked doc (or read the linked dupe, it's easier to get through).

Comment: The multiplication is not dangerous. It's the 3.6 that's dangerous. There's no such number (in floating point) as 3.6; it's rounded to the nearest floating point value.

Comment: Actually I partly take that back. Since the approximation of 3.6 uses all available mantissa bits and 21 is not a power of 2, the multiplication will also result in rounding at the tail.

Comment: The *really* "dangerous" part is the repeated additions.  Each addition can introduce a small rounding error, which will be compounded every time the addition is repeated.

Comment: @R. Right. It's the 3.6 that's dangerous. printf (" incr ==  %.20f \n", 3.6); incredibly gives incr ==  3.60000000000000008882

Comment: You should use at least 53 total places (50 or 51 after the radix here, I think) to get the full value.